# UseHttpsRedirection and IIS production deployment in .NET 7.0

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, ssl, iis, deployment

I am in the process of upgrading my .NET Framework application (UI and API) to use .NET 7.0.

I have just deployed my application to my production server and I am met with an issue.

As I am using - `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` when I browse to my website locally on the server on localhost url it is not finding a valid certificate and I am having to proceed when prompted in the browser for the page to become available.

In my previous .NET Framework version, there was no setting for `UseHttpsRedirection` and I could browse to my application over HTTP just fine, and when accessing my application outwith the server from a browser where I am using an AWS ELB to handle traffic to the site with a listener on HTTPS, I have imported my SSL certificate into the cert manager in AWS and referenced it in Route 53 in the DNS record for my site, which works fine.

Unfortunately when AWS tries to redirect to the latest version the application is timing out and I am perplexed as to why?

I have tried to create my certificate again as a pfx and import it into IIS on the prod server however when browsing over localhost it says the cert is not valid, I can only imagine this is because the cert is exclusive to my domain name? But is this even a necessary step?

I removed the `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` and also modified my `launchSettings.json` to remove the https start url (to try and mimic the framework version). On doing this when AWS redirected me to my app, the starting url was over HTTP (and timed out) however when I modified the URL to use HTTPS I saw my app! I don't understand why my .NET framework app worked without any modification and was always served over HTTPS outwith the server, but the latest upgrade doesn't have the same behavior?

I have rolled back to my previous version until I figure this out.

**Edit after VonC suggestions -**

VonC was correct in his assumptions, however I also had to make 2 small code changes. I removed `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` (as all traffic is handled securely internally by my AWS VPC, and I also added to my program.cs in the UI the following -

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions()
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

Also anyone with the same issue, I had to modify my HTTP listner on the ELB so that it redirected to HTTPS automatically.

Comment: "But is this even a necessary step?" Microsoft has its decision here, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41990

Comment: If you could shed some more light please @LexLi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I browse to my website locally on the server on localhost url it is not finding a valid certificate and I am having to proceed when prompted in the browser for the page to become available.

That is expected:  If you are browsing to the site using localhost or the server's local IP, the certificate is not going to be valid because it is issued for your domain name, not for localhost or an IP address. It does not affect users accessing the site via your domain name.

---

> In my previous .NET Framework version, there was no setting for UseHttpsRedirection and I could browse to my application over HTTP just fine, and when accessing my application outwith the server from a browser where I am using an AWS ELB to handle traffic to the site with a listener on HTTPS, I have imported my SSL certificate into the cert manager in AWS and referenced it in Route 53 in the DNS record for my site, which works fine.

That means the HTTPS termination was handled at the level of the AWS Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) in your previous setup.
The SSL/TLS certificate was installed on the load balancer, and the load balancer was responsible for encrypting and decrypting traffic to and from the client. This is a common pattern and is generally recommended because it offloads the computational overhead of SSL/TLS encryption/decryption from the application servers.

When a client connected to your website, the connection would be over HTTPS to the ELB. However, the connection from the ELB to your application servers could be over HTTP, which is why you did not need to use `UseHttpsRedirection` in your application.

With your upgrade to .NET 7 and the inclusion of `UseHttpsRedirection`, the application is now enforcing HTTPS for all connections. This could be causing issues with the way traffic is routed between the ELB and your application servers.

If you want to maintain the previous behavior, where HTTPS is handled at the ELB level and HTTP is used between the ELB and your servers, you might consider removing the `UseHttpsRedirection` middleware from your application.

Remember that this approach is fine from a security standpoint as long as the traffic between the ELB and your application servers is within a secure network, such as within an AWS VPC. This is known as SSL/TLS termination at the load balancer.

However, it is also worth noting that .NET 7 has introduced the ability to specify separate HTTP and HTTPS profiles (as illustrated in [`dotnet/aspnetcore` issue 44722](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44722#issuecomment-1290621757)), which might give you more flexibility in managing your traffic patterns.

---

The OP adds:

> I removed `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` (as all traffic is handled securely internally by my AWS VPC).
> And I also added to my `program.`cs in the UI the following
>
> ```cs
> app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions()
> {
>    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
> });
> ```
>
> Also anyone with the same issue, I had to modify my HTTP listner on the ELB so that it redirected to HTTPS automatically.

By making these changes, you are delegating the SSL termination to the ELB, while still maintaining secure communication for your clients.

This is a common configuration and is considered a best practice for deploying applications behind load balancers or reverse proxies.

Comment: Very thorough answer, this all makes sense to me apart from one main point. If you notice the last section of my question I did try removing the UseHttpsRedirection, however when accessed through the ELB after auth, the starting URL was over http, only manually modifying it to https could I see my app as I have an https listener. The previous version starting url defaulted to use https and required no modification? You are also correct that the elb and app server use http rule.

Comment: @Ebikeneser After you removed UseHttpsRedirection, the application no longer enforced HTTPS. However, it seems that the AWS ELB was no longer redirecting HTTP traffic to HTTPS.  I check the AWS environment, specifically the security settings, listeners, and rules in your ALB to confirm that HTTP is allowed and properly routed. If your ALB is set to only listen to and accept HTTPS, then any HTTP request might lead to a timeout or similar issue.

Comment: Ok, and if I set up an HTTP listener, is this at all a security risk, as you are right currently I am getting a timeout before modifying the url? I will implement these changes and get back to you with the results. Just to be clear, I take it I should install the certificate on my app server as well as having it on the ELB, this is common practice?

Comment: @Ebikeneser Setting up an HTTP listener is not itself is not necessarily a security risk. However, it can become a risk if it is not handled properly. If you have an HTTP listener that does not automatically redirect to HTTPS, then any data sent over this connection will not be encrypted and could be intercepted. It is generally best practice to have your HTTP listener set to automatically redirect to HTTPS to ensure that all data is always transmitted securely. If you are getting a timeout, it may be because there is no correct response set up for HTTP requests.

Comment: @Ebikeneser Setting up a redirection from HTTP to HTTPS can resolve this.

Comment: @Ebikeneser Installing your SSL certificate on both your app server and ELB is indeed common practice. This provides end-to-end encryption of data. The certificate on the ELB will secure the data between the client and the ELB, and the certificate on the app server will secure the data between the ELB and the app server. However, if your architecture is designed such that all external traffic goes through the ELB and is then passed to the app server over a secure network, you may not need the certificate on the app server. That last case is usually what I do: no certificate on the application.

Comment: I am very clear now @VonC, you mentioned earlier about traffic between the app server and the ELB, currently I have a security group rule that allows for HTTP traffic but not HTTPS, my thinking is if I create a rule to allow HTTPS traffic between the 2, and leave in the UseHttpsRedirection this SHOULD work without any cert install in the app! I will be retrying all of this on Sunday so I will let you know. I appreciate your time massively.

Comment: it is now working! Kudos to your explanation, there were a couple small code changes I made also that I will append in the original question. Thank you.

Comment: @Ebikeneser Great, well done! Don't forget to post an answer of your own, highlighting the changes you had to make, for others to learn from.

Comment: I have appended the changes required to get it working in the original question, should I create an answer also? I wasn't sure if the edits would suffice seeming as I marked yours as the answer?

Comment: @Ebikeneser OK, make sense. I will edit my answer soon.

Comment: @Ebikeneser I have included your changes in the answer.